# Multithreading slower than Singlethreading

Tags: c#, multithreading, performance

I have the following Code (complete content of 'Program.cs' of console application). 
The single threaded execution of 'countUp' till 'countUp4' takes 13 sec., the multi threaded execution 21 sec..

I have a Intel Core i5-2400 @ 3.10 GHz, 8 GB Ram, Windows 7 64 Bit. So why is the multi threaded execution slower than the single threaded one?

Is multithreading just useful for not blocking the main routine of simple c# applications? When does multithreading give me an advantage in execution speed?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static int counter = 0;
        static int counter2 = 0;
        static int counter3 = 0;
        static int counter4 = 0;

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Without multithreading:");
            Console.WriteLine("Start:" + DateTime.Now.ToString());

            countUp();
            countUp2();
            countUp3();
            countUp4();

            Console.WriteLine("");
            Console.WriteLine("With multithreading:");
            Console.WriteLine("Start:" + DateTime.Now.ToString());

            Thread thread1 = new Thread(new ThreadStart(countUp));
            thread1.Start();
            Thread thread2 = new Thread(new ThreadStart(countUp2));
            thread2.Start();
            Thread thread3 = new Thread(new ThreadStart(countUp3));
            thread3.Start();
            Thread thread4 = new Thread(new ThreadStart(countUp4));
            thread4.Start();

            Console.Read();
        }

        static void countUp()
        {
            for (double i = 0; i < 1000000000; i++)
            {
                counter++;
            }

            Console.WriteLine(counter.ToString());
            Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Now.ToString());
        }

        static void countUp2()
        {
            for (double i = 0; i < 1000000000; i++)
            {
                counter2++;
            }

            Console.WriteLine(counter2.ToString());
            Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Now.ToString());
        }

        static void countUp3()
        {
            for (double i = 0; i < 1000000000; i++)
            {
                counter3++;
            }

            Console.WriteLine(counter3.ToString());
            Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Now.ToString());
        }

        static void countUp4()
        {
            for (double i = 0; i < 1000000000; i++)
            {
                counter4++;
            }

            Console.WriteLine(counter4.ToString());
            Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Now.ToString());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I am suprised this even works... Are you not accessing the UI thread from the background ones? Is this the actual code?

Comment: Nothing of the ordinary here. The Console propably (this is just my guess) needs to be synchronized, thus all threads are waiting on each other. Its a widely common misinformation that multithreading is automatically faster. You have to deal with synchronization, context switches and so on.

Comment: First of all, DateTime.Now is a horrible way to time anything, use the `Stopwatch` class instead.  Second, not all code benefits from multi-threading.

Comment: @Killercam What UI thread?  It's a console application

Comment: Maybe UI thread is not the best word, but still i'm pretty sure that the console needs to synchronize and handle the output in one thread.

Comment: Actually, Console is synchronized already.

Comment: @killercam: it's the actual working code.

Comment: @james michael hare: i think using DateTime.Now serves in this case.

Comment: @KaiHartmann: Not really, it's heavy and it is innacurate.  Whenever you want to time a block of code, `System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch` is generally lighter and more precise.

Comment: @james michael hare: Ok, thanks for pointing that out. I will give it a try.

Comment: @KaiHartmann No, it really doesn't.  It has a *much* lower level of precision (each tick is 16 ms, as opposed to the several nanoseconds of a stopwatch).

Comment: I tried Stopwatch, you're right it's better suited for timing code execution because of it's finer granularity, and I will use it in the future. But neverless the code here differs in seconds. The time measured is the same as when I did with DateTime in that regard.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Here's a cause that you might not see coming: [false sharing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc872851.aspx) because those 4 ints all sit side by side in memory.

**Update - MSDN mags from previous years are only available as `.chm` files now - so you have to grab the ['October 2008' edition of the MSDN Mag from here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/magazine/msdn-magazine-issues) and, after downloading, you must remember to right-click and 'unblock' the file from the file properties dialog in Windows Explorer (other OSs are available!) before opening it.  You're looking for a column called '.Net Matters' by Stephen Toub, Igor Ostrovsky, and Huseyin Yildiz**

The article (read it all - it's brilliant) shows how values that are side by side in memory can end up causing blocking when updated because they all sit on the same cache line.  This is very low-level blocking that you can't disable from your .Net code.  You can, however force the data to be spaced further apart so that you guarantee, or at least increase the likelihood, that each value will be on a different cache line.

The article uses arrays - but it's just possible it's affecting you here.

To follow up the suggestion below, you might be able to prove/disprove this by changing your code ever-so-slightly:

```
class Program 
{ 
    class CounterHolder {
       private int[] fakeInts = new int[1024];
       public int Value = 0;
    }
    static CounterHolder counter1 = new CounterHolder(); 
    static CounterHolder counter2 = new CounterHolder(); 
    static CounterHolder counter3 = new CounterHolder(); 
    static CounterHolder counter4 = new CounterHolder();
```

And then modify your thread functions to manipulate the public field `Value` on each of the counter holders.

I've made those arrays really much bigger than they need to be in the hope that it'll prove it better :)

Comment: Should be easy enough to prove out, @KaiHartmann, why don't you put each int to increment local to each method and see if it makes a difference.

Comment: Yep, just tried it.  Multiple threads are faster if you make the counter local.

Comment: @JohnnyHK have updated with another idea that should help prove it too.

Comment: +1 Well spotted! I also wrote a article on false sharing: [here](http://simplygenius.net/Article/FalseSharing)

Comment: This works like a charm. Singlethreading took 15 sec., multithreading 4 sec.

Comment: I never new this. I was interested so ran the same example using stopwatches and TPL. The results cut the time taken for the multi-threaded version by over 50%. This is not something I was aware of so thanks... All the best.

Comment: This is the winner for me, but I want to check Frederic's post as well, has anybody something to say about the joining?

Comment: @KaiHartmann yes the Join() is correct - although because of the `Console.Read` the application doesn't exit till you hit a key, and since you don't hit key till you see all the results it should be fine :)

Comment: Thx @AndrasZoltan. I somewhat misunderstood Frederic's post, so you got the 'right answer' right away. I still wonder, why Frederic got 'correct' results with the same code that did not work for me...

Comment: sounds odd,  but might have been single core...   or a processor with a different cache architecture.  its all about the bare metal in this case - which we are not used to saying in dot net.

Comment: the link to MSDN is broken - do you have an updated one?

Comment: @mcmillab have added an update with instructions on how to get hold of the MSDN mag now that they're no longer online.

Answer (score 5):

Andreas Zaltan's is the answer. Take the code

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        //static int counter = 0;
        //static int counter2 = 0;
        //static int counter3 = 0;
        //static int counter4 = 0;

        class CounterHolder
        {
            private int[] fakeInts = new int[1024];
            public int Value = 0;
        }
        static CounterHolder counter1 = new CounterHolder();
        static CounterHolder counter2 = new CounterHolder();
        static CounterHolder counter3 = new CounterHolder();
        static CounterHolder counter4 = new CounterHolder(); 

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Without multithreading:");
            Console.WriteLine("Start: " + DateTime.Now.ToString());

            Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch();
            sw.Start();

            countUp();
            countUp2();
            countUp3();
            countUp4();

            sw.Stop();
            Console.WriteLine("Time taken = " + sw.Elapsed.ToString());

            Console.WriteLine("\nWith multithreading:");
            Console.WriteLine("Start: " + DateTime.Now.ToString());
            sw.Reset();
            sw.Start();

            Task task1 = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => countUp());
            Task task2 = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => countUp2());
            Task task3 = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => countUp3());
            Task task4 = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => countUp4());
            var continuation = Task.Factory.ContinueWhenAll(new[] { task1, task2, task3, task4 }, tasks =>
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Total Time taken = " + sw.Elapsed.ToString());
            });
            Console.Read();
        }

        static void countUp()
        {
            Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch();
            sw.Start();
            for (double i = 0; i < 1000000000; i++)
                counter1.Value++;
            sw.Stop();
            Console.WriteLine("Task countup took: " + sw.Elapsed.ToString());
        }

        static void countUp2()
        {
            Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch();
            sw.Start();
            for (double i = 0; i < 1000000000; i++)
                counter2.Value++;
            sw.Stop();
            Console.WriteLine("Task countUP2 took: " + sw.Elapsed.ToString());
        }

        static void countUp3()
        {
            Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch();
            sw.Start();
            for (double i = 0; i < 1000000000; i++)
                counter3.Value++;
            sw.Stop();
            Console.WriteLine("Task countUP2 took: " + sw.Elapsed.ToString());
        }

        static void countUp4()
        {
            Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch();
            sw.Start();
            for (double i = 0; i < 1000000000; i++)
                counter4.Value++;
            sw.Stop();
            Console.WriteLine("Task countUP2 took: " + sw.Elapsed.ToString());
        }
    } 
}
```

Run it with the intergers and you get the multi-thrreadded version running ever so slightly slower.

```
Serial: 13.88s
Multi-threaded: 14.01
```

Run it using the suggestion above you get the following

[image]

I have posted this for clarity...

Answer (score 1):

I rewrote your code with StopWatch. Multi-threading is faster than Single-threading on my computer (times below).

Also, you need to call the method **Join** on the threads to be sure that they finished before exiting the program.

Time elapsed without multithreading:: 00:00:21.6897179

Time elapsed with multithreading:: 00:00:14.7893703

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static int counter = 0;
        static int counter2 = 0;
        static int counter3 = 0;
        static int counter4 = 0;

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Stopwatch stopwatch = new Stopwatch();
            stopwatch.Start();

            countUp();
            countUp2();
            countUp3();
            countUp4();

            stopwatch.Stop();
            Console.WriteLine("Time elapsed without multithreading:: {0}",
        stopwatch.Elapsed);

            stopwatch.Reset();
            stopwatch.Start();

            Thread thread1 = new Thread(new ThreadStart(countUp));
            thread1.Start();
            Thread thread2 = new Thread(new ThreadStart(countUp2));
            thread2.Start();
            Thread thread3 = new Thread(new ThreadStart(countUp3));
            thread3.Start();
            Thread thread4 = new Thread(new ThreadStart(countUp4));
            thread4.Start();

            thread1.Join();
            thread2.Join();
            thread3.Join();
            thread4.Join();

            stopwatch.Stop();
            Console.WriteLine("Time elapsed with multithreading:: {0}",
        stopwatch.Elapsed);

            Console.Read();
        }

        static void countUp()
        {
            for (double i = 0; i < 1000000000; i++)
            {
                counter++;
            }
        }

        static void countUp2()
        {
            for (double i = 0; i < 1000000000; i++)
            {
                counter2++;
            }
        }

        static void countUp3()
        {
            for (double i = 0; i < 1000000000; i++)
            {
                counter3++;
            }
        }

        static void countUp4()
        {
            for (double i = 0; i < 1000000000; i++)
            {
                counter4++;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I will check on this tomorrow. Andras Zoltan's hint solved my problem, but perhaps this is correct, too...

Comment: Ah, I read to fast. The Join is just for making sure the threads are finished... I thought it does something to solve the problem, but it does not. So I wonder, why it is faster on your machine. Is there no locking as it was described by Andras Zoltan? Btw. the part with the joins is helpful nevertheless...

Comment: I thought that the Console.Read() was there to prevent the main thread from exiting early and so resulting in early termination of the other threads. - if so, why bother Join()ing the threads?

Answer (score 0):

I'm no expert on multi-threading, but I think what you're doing there is essentially just moving the work away from the UI thread.

That's by no means a bad thing if you have some long-running or intensive work to do, as it allows you to keep a responsive UI for the end user. To run things like that quicker, you'll want to look into parallel processing, if my memory services me correctly.

Comment: Assuming you mean parallel processing by "that", I know. I said that's what he'd want to look at to run that code quicker. I may have misunderstood your comment, but it doesn't describe what "that" is all that clearly.

Comment: I meant that your whole post is just wrong.  It's a console app, so there is no UI thread.  He's not just making it more responsive, he's actually doing separate (useless, but it's just an example) tasks in parallel that should be sped up as a result.

Answer (score 0):

First, use the StopWatch class from the System.Runtime.Diagnostic namespace for measuring, instead of DateTime.

Second, you do not clear the 'Counters' after you synchronously execution.

You should use parallelisation for all the threads, than it is faster! The initializing new threads are costly. You can use the ThreadPool by the way.

Comment: I don't think we can assume the TPL is faster either.  It still has scheduling costs.

Comment: It doesn't matter that the counters aren't reset.  It won't make the code any faster/slower; and they're just there to consume processor cycles.  As for thread pooling, in the example given it shouldn't be dramatically different in this specific context.

Comment: Using ThreadPool gives nearly the same result in execution time.

Comment: @KaiHartmann That's because the thread pool starts empty, is given enough tasks that it will need to create a thread for each, and then never re-uses any of them.  If you created many more smaller units of work then a threadpool would likely be better than explicitly creating threads.

Comment: Yes, you are right, in this case the reset doesn't matters. But if you have a complex calculation it matters! You should always use the same conditions for performance tests..

Answer (score 0):

As Joeb454 said you got to looking for parallel processing in that case.
Your multi threading just slow the execution because create a new thread take a "long" time.

Comment: Creating a thread takes a matter of milliseconds.  I don't think that's a "long" time in this context.

Comment: The execution of the task is on the order of several seconds.  The time spend creating the threads will pale in comparison.  If the execution time of the actual tasks was much smaller then this is a likely problem.